# elasticsearch validation of aggregation queries

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

I run simple aggregration query in marvel and get the result without problem:
[image]

But when I validate the same query, it returns false and in explantion it says "QueryParsingException"... 
[image]

I can validate other queries if it works valid is true if not valid false, even my aggre query works and give me documens its validation result false.. Why is that ? its some kind of bug here ? or ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your validation URL should look like this instead:

```
dota2/_validate/query?explain=true
```

and not like this

```
dota2/_search/_validate/query?explain=true
         ^
         |
    remove this
```

Comment: I tried but still same.. even if it is not, I can use _search in validation with other queries without problem.. There might be something diffirent for aggregations I think..

Comment: Oh, you're right, I missed that part. The `_validate` endpoint only supports validating a query and not aggs, indeed.

Comment: I see.. then maybe I should check shard status. Thank you.

Comment: Hello, Can you check my new post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32466163/elasticsearch-date-range-query-witn-nest-api Thank you.