# elasticsearch date_range query witn nest api

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I run a query in marvel plugin and it works fine(return 4 document) as you see below
[image]

And I want to make this query in C# with NEST, I expected same result with the plugin for this expression but it returns 0..

function call:

```
EsCodes myes = new EsCodes();
                myes.CreateConnection("localhost", "dota2");
                var result = myes.getDatasBetweenDates("01/01/2010 00:00:00", "01/01/2015 00:00:00");
```

connection:

```
private static ElasticClient es = new ElasticClient();
      public void CreateConnection(string hostname, string defaultIndex)
        {
            var node = new Uri(string.Format("http://{0}:9200", hostname));
            var settings = new ConnectionSettings(node).SetDefaultIndex(defaultIndex).UsePrettyResponses();
            es = new ElasticClient(settings);
        }
```

and function:

```
public List<IndexModel> getDatasBetweenDates(string startdate, string enddate)
        {
            ElasticClient myes = this.getConnection();
            List<IndexModel> indices = new List<IndexModel>();
            if (myes != null)
            {
                var result = myes.Search<dynamic>(q => q.Query(p => p.Range(v => v.OnField("dateofplay").GreaterOrEquals(startdate).LowerOrEquals(enddate))).Size(10)).Documents;
            }
                ...
                return indices;
            }
```

What is wrong with that ?

**EDIT:** I recognized the url created by NEST contaims "../dota2/object/_search.."
I don't understand why it included that kind of parameter.. its the point of my issue. why it generates object in the url ?

Comment: Please provide the relevant C#/NEST code in textual form instead of in a screenshot. It will make it easier for others to search in the future.

Comment: you are right. done.

Comment: Can you also make your curl query match your C#/NEST query? In your curl request you are searching a single index, in C#/NEST - all indices. If there is problem with adding other indices it will be more obvious in curl.

Comment: @imotov I added connection function, I am seaching same index in nest too. but returns 0 documents..

Comment: The dates are in DateTime format ?

Comment: @dzomba Yes, all dates in "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss" format. its same for field type("date") in elasticsearch

Comment: And if you try with only the gte condition it s returning something?

Comment: @dzomba yes  it still returns 0..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that you're not using the same dates in both queries.

In Marvel you use `"22/06/2010 00:00:00"` and `"16/09/2015 00:00:00"`

In your code you use `"22/06/2012 00:00:00"` and `"16/09/2014 00:00:00"`

So maybe that's the only reason why you don't get any results from your code.

Comment: Unfortunately it is not.. I missed before take ps of that but both of date parameters are same ..edited that.

Comment: I think I got the reason.. there is an extra parameter in the url posted nest. which meanless, "/dota2/object/_search.."

Comment: Oh, yes that's probably not the correct mapping type, should be `agust`.

Comment: Yes I solved the issue by edit query with "Search<dynamic>(q => q.Index("dota2").AllTypes()..." so its ok now. Thank you valentine. You always inspire me :)